# Heroku App can Interact with Heroku-postgres locally, but not When Deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am making a Flask app for a very simple game that I am hosting on Heroku, and it interacts with a Heroku-Postgres "hobby-dev" level database.  When hosted locally, the app can interact with the database perfectly (.  However, when I deploy it on Heroku, it will usually crash not long after it tries to interact with the database.  Pages that don't require this interaction work fine.  Specifically, I receive the following two errors in Heroku's logs:

```
2021-05-19T19:23:20.943811+00:00 app[web.1]:cur = db.cursor() 
2021-05-19T19:23:20.943812+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

and...

```
2021-05-19T19:20:35.682211+00:00 app[web.1]:     cur.execute("select * from mock_table;")
2021-05-19T19:20:35.682211+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```

I have a few theories for the cause based on research, but I am not sure:

- The database connection is only created once at the very beginning of the Flask app.
- I store the Python code for interacting with the database in a separate module.  I make the original connection **once** using psycopg2.connect(...) in the Flask app module, but I pass it to another module and its methods to actually interact with the database.
- Something else causes the database connection to end

Are any of these close, and does anyone understand what I am missing?  I can provide more info if it is required, but I didn't want to put too much.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/@philamersune/fixing-ssl-error-decryption-failed-or-bad-record-mac-d668e71a5409), one possible reason for the errors I am receiving is a timed-out database connection.  Thus, all I had to do was place my database calling methods in a try-except block and re-establish the connection if an error occurred.  As an example,

```
cur.execute("select * from mock_table;")
```

could be replaced with...

```
try:
    cur.execute("select * from mock_table;")
except:
    #remake connection here
    db.connect(host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password)
    cur.execute("select * from mock_table;")
```

It isn't the most elegant solution, and it might have some flaws, but it has fixed the issue successfully so far, so I figured that I would share it.